# Copy and rename a file every minute

Tags: powershell

So I am trying to copy files from a folder to another one. The files in this folder are overwritten every minute by another program. I want to get a copy of each file every minute before it gets overwritten and save it somewhere else. See example structure below:

```
Folder 1 # gets overwritten every minute
a.txt
a_backup.txt

Folder 2
a1.txt
a1_backup.txt
a2.txt
a2_backup.txt
a3.txt
a3_backup.txt
a4.txt
a4_backup.txt
```

It would be even better if the files in Folder 2 would contain the date and time of when they were copied in their names.
I came up with the following:

```
$Source = 'C:\Users\Source'
$Destination = 'C:\Users\Target'
Do{
Copy-Item $Source\* -Destination $Destination
sleep -s 59
} while($true)
```

However, this does not do the job completely as I am only copying the file once and then copy the same file again when it's overwritten...

Any help is warmly welcome!

Comment: So, you'd need to append it - in your example, with an iterator.  I think the question becomes then "*when would you stop*?"  i.e.: Once you reach 1000?  One Million?  When do you rollover, if ever?

Comment: thanks for anwsering, I want to stop it manually. When I close the above mentioned program, I'll close the Powershell as well and thereby stop the script from running. How'd I append it with an iterator though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source | % { copy-item $_.FullName -Destination "$Destination\$((Get-Date).ToString("MMddyyyy-hhmmss"))$($_.Name)" }
```

This statement will take care of it but what it will not do is hide the exceptions and failures you will get while the file is being written to.

`$_.FullName` includes the full path.. can be used as source
`$_.Name` gives you the filename only (without the path) 
`(Get-Date).ToString("MMddyyyy-hhmmss")` gives you the date in format specified in `ToString()`. Since the file is updated every minute, you will need to include the minutes and seconds in your filename as well.

Comment: I think the date format you mean should start with 'MM'  (Month), not 'mm' (minutes)

Comment: You are correct.. I have updated the answer to reflect MM for month

Answer (score 2):

New on giving answers but here's my proposal.

Get Content , and out to another file with current time as of writing maybe? Of course include your loop around it

```
 Get-Content C:\log.txt | Out-File "Log.$([System.Math]::Round((date -UFormat %s),0)).txt""
```